# How to Reordering the objects from ManyToManyField in Django?

Tags: python, django

i have two models, one is Articles and second is Pool, if i try to Reorder the positioning of objects of Articles or Pool just need to change the model name into `get_object_or_404(Articles, pk=int(b['pk']))`. But i want to Reordering the position of `Pool.articles` from (ManyToManyField) inside of Pool articles.
i'm confused how can i use the position Field in Pool model for change position of `articles`. I would be grateful for any help.

the code below of view.py is getting error `First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'ManyToManyDescriptor'.`

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    position = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)

class Pool(models.Model):
    pool_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article)
```

views.py

```
def SortAble(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        arts = json.loads(request.POST.get('sort'))
        for b in arts:
            try:
                art = get_object_or_404(Pool.articles, pk=int(b['pk']))
                art.position = b['order']
                art.save()
            except KeyError:
                pass
    return HttpResponse('saved')
```

Comment: What is `arts`?

Comment: really sorry for this my Question is updated please take a look...

Comment: `Pool.articles.all()`, but it is not a good idea to fetch all these items with one query per iteration.

Comment: `get_object_or_404(Article, pk=int(b['pk']))` should work if you are passing the pk of the article. If you want to sort articles with respect to pools then you need extra fields and a through model in which these fields would be present

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes you are write! i'm confused where i need to define the extra field would you like to explain it

Comment: Look into [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) in django's documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to handle this would be to convert the list of `arts` into a lookup for pk -> order, then use `bulk_update`. You can reduce the number of queries from 2N to 2.

```
arts_map = {art["pk"]: art["order"] for art in arts}
updated_articles = []
for article in Article.objects.filter(pk__in=arts_map.keys()):
    article.position = arts_map[article.pk]
    updated_articles.append(article)
if updated_articles:
    Article.objects.bulk_update(updated_articles, ['position'])
```

Comment: I don't know the shape and contents of `arts`. My answer conveys what the general solution is. You should be able to take it from here and manipulate it to fit your situation precisely.

Comment: but it's not rendering in the template side to `obj = get_object_or_404(Pool, pk=pk).order_by('position')` how can i show reordered articles inside of Pool detail views

Comment: You can access the pool's articles, sorted by position via: `pool_instance.articles.order_by('position')`

Comment: can i define this into a little function because i don't understand how can i use were i can define pool_instance or were i use it. please

Comment: I wrote `pool_instance` be an instance of the `Pool` model. You can fetch one via `get_object_or_404`, `Pool.objects.get()` or iterate over a list via `Pool.objects.filter()`. Does that help explain how to get that?

Comment: you mean like this `def PoolDetail(request, pk):                                                                 obj = get_object_or_404(Pool, pk=pk)pool_instance.articles.order_by('position')
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'object': obj})`

Comment: I think we've gone beyond the scope of your original question.

Comment: please dear if you don't mind. i just want to know i'm new in programming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227358/discussion-between-schillingt-and-afi).

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you need to pass a model, manager or `QuerySet`, but `Poo.articles` is not any of these.

You can however use `.all()` to convert it to a queryset:

```
def SortAble(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        arts = json.loads(request.POST.get('sort'))
        for b in arts:
            try:
                art = get_object_or_404(Artice, pk=int(b['pk']))
                art.position = b['order']
                art.save()
            except KeyError:
                pass
    return HttpResponse('saved')
```

It however does not look very efficient to do this, since now you make a query *per* item in the list of dictionaries. Furthermore if for example an item is not avaiable, you will update items before the missing item, which might get the system in an inconsistent state.

It is thus better to obtain the items in bulk, update these, and then save the updates at the database side:

```
from django.http import HPool.articlesttp404

def SortAble(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        arts = json.loads(request.POST.get('sort'))
        try:
            items = {
                item.pk: item for item in Article.objects.filter(
                    pk__in=[a['pk'] for a in arts]
                )
            }
        except:
            raise Http404
        for a in arts:
            try:
                item = items[a['pk']]
            except KeyError:
                raise Http404
            item.position = a['order']
        Article.bulk_update(items.values(), fields=['position'])
    return HttpResponse('saved')
```

Comment: dear it's getting `'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'`

Comment: @afi: hold on, but `Pool` is not a `Pool` object, it is the `Pool` class, so then the idea of using the many-to-many relation is downright wrong.

Comment: it's getting ` invalid syntax` inside of `    items = {item.pk: item for Article.objects.filter(pk__in=[a['pk'] for a in arts])}` Code

Comment: and item is not define